# AngularJS Expression Not Working Correctly in ng-src with JSF

Tags: angularjs, jsf, jsf-2, angularjs-directive

The angularjs module. the `products` array contains 2 product objects that will be added as a property of the controller.

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    var products = [
        {
        title: "Dummy Title 1",
        description: "Dummy Description 1",
        image: "dummy_image_1.jpg"
        },
        {
            title: "Dummy Title 2",
            description: "Dummy Description 2",
            image: "dummy_image_2.jpg"
        }
    ];


    app.controller('myController', function () {
        this.products = products;
    });
})();
```

The JSF Page, if I remove `images/{{product.image}}` with the actual image file name such as `images/dummy_image_1.jpg`, the images are displayed, but if I use angularjs expression instead, then nothing is shown. Please note that other expressions in the loop work besides `{{product.image}}`. If I add `{{product.image}}` somewhere else, then it displays the filename correctly, but used in `ng-srs`, it prints nothing if I view the html. I don't know why it is.

```
<h:form>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="myController as controller">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-10">
                    Hello&#160;<b><h:outputText value="#{user.userName}"/></b><br/>
                    <h:commandLink action="cart" value="Cart"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr/>

            <div ng-repeat="product in controller.products">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="media">
                        <div class="media-left">
                            <img class="media-object" ng-src="images/{{product.image}}"/> <!--If I replace that expression with a the image file name, it shows the image -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">{{product.title}}</h4>
                            <span class="caption">{{product.description}}</span><br/>
                            <h:commandLink action="cart" value="Add to cart"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: give a try using `ng-attr-src="{{'images/'+product.image}}"`

Comment: try angularfaces. They solved lots of things…

Comment: @pankajparkar add your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks, your solution works

Comment: @Dummy check I've added an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes using interpolation `{{}}` won't evaluate & update value of attribute (most often this happens in IE). The way to do this is using `ng-src` directive with interpolation `{{}}` this will add `src` to the `img` tag after evaluation interpolation directive.

**Markup**

```
<div class="media-left">
    <img class="media-object" ng-src="{{'images/'+product.image}}"/> 
    <!--If I replace that expression with a the image file name, it shows the image -->
</div>
```

**Alternative**

The other way would be using `ng-attr` directive which add `attribute` with evaluated `value`. This will ensure you everytime that the interpolated value has been assigned to the `attribute` mentioned it in `ng-attr` (the part after ng-attr is considered as attribute to be added, suppose we have `ng-attr-value="{{someVar}}"` then angular will evaluate `someVar` and then assign that value to value attribute on that element.

**Markup**

```
<div class="media-left">
    <img class="media-object" ng-attr-src="{{'images/'+product.image}}"/> 
    <!--If I replace that expression with a the image file name, it shows the image -->
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know if `ng-attr-src`, I used `ng-src` but with your suggested form of the expression instead of the way I did.

Comment: @Dummy I've edited my answer with both way..Glad to help you..Thanks :)